# Automatically generate tabel that shows grade corresponding to number of points within exam

Tags: tables, exam, automation, points

I would like to automatically add a table that shows the height of the grade corresponging to the number of points.

So far, I have

```
\tcprintroundresult{1}
\tcsetcoltype{|c|c|}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}c|}
\vtablecalc [1]{points}{x=0,1,2,3,4,\numpoints}{grade}{x/\numpoints *9+1}
```

which works. But I would really like the x automatically add up to the total number of points. Anyone any suggestion how to fix this?

[image]

And additional, is it possible  to automatically divide this table over more tables if it gets too long?

Comment: Look in the aux file for something like `\gdef\totalpoints{...}`

Comment: the \numpoints gives the total points. So in above situation this is 8. But I would like to have 5,6,7 automatically filled in.

Comment: If you are loading tcolorbox, then you already have \foreach available.  This could be used instead of \vtablecalc (whatever package that is from).

Comment: Looks perfect. I'm gonna give it a try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a former classmate I have a solution which fulfills most of my desires. To be honest; I haven't got a clue how most of it is done. But it works fine.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage{tikz}

%-----------------------------------------
% This is some prework that needs to be done
%-----------------------------------------
\makeatletter
   \providecommand{\exam@numpoints}{1}%
   \newcommand{\GetNumPoints}{\exam@numpoints}%
    \newcommand*{\@MyTempTableTokens}{}%
    \newtoks\@tabtoks
    %%% assignments to \@tabtoks must be global, because they are done in \foreach
    \newcommand\AddTableTokens[1]{\global\@tabtoks\expandafter{\the\@tabtoks#1}}
    \newcommand\eAddTableTokens[1]{% 
        \protected@edef\@MyTempTableTokens{#1}%
        \expandafter\AddTableTokens\expandafter{\@MyTempTableTokens}}
    %%% variable should always be operated on either always locally or always globally
    \newcommand*\ResetTableTokens{\global\@tabtoks{}}
    \newcommand*\PrintTableTokens{\the\@tabtoks}
\makeatother
\newcommand*{\NormFormule}[1]{%
    \pgfmathparse{
        9 * ( #1 / \GetNumPoints ) + 1
    }
    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=1, fixed zerofill, use comma]{\pgfmathresult}}


%-----------------------------------------
% This is the command for making the table
%-----------------------------------------
\newcommand{\maketable}{\bigskip
\Huge Grading Table\bigskip\\\normalsize
    \ResetTableTokens
    \foreach \i in {0,...,14}   %THIS IS WHERE I GOT STUCK!
    {\eAddTableTokens{\i & \noexpand\NormFormule{\i} \\}}{}                 
        \begin{minipage}[t]{.23\textwidth}\centering$(1{,}0-3{,}2)$\\       
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                \hline
                \textbf{score}&\textbf{grade}\\\hline\centering
                \PrintTableTokens
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage}  
    \ResetTableTokens
    \foreach \i in {15,...,29} {\eAddTableTokens{\i & \noexpand\NormFormule{\i} \\}}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{.23\textwidth}\centering$(3{,}3-5{,}4)$\\
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                \hline
                \textbf{score}&\textbf{grade}\\\hline\centering
                \PrintTableTokens
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage}          
    \ResetTableTokens
    \foreach \i in {30,...,44} {\eAddTableTokens{\i & \noexpand\NormFormule{\i} \\}}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{.23\textwidth}\centering$(5{,}5-7{,}7)$\\
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                \hline
                \textbf{score}&\textbf{grade}\\\hline\centering
                \PrintTableTokens
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage}      
    \ResetTableTokens
    \foreach \i in {45,...,\GetNumPoints} {\eAddTableTokens{\i & \noexpand\NormFormule{\i} \\}}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{.23\textwidth}\centering$(7{,}8-10{,}0)$\\
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                \hline
                \textbf{score}&\textbf{grade}\\\hline\centering
                \PrintTableTokens
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage}
}


%-----------------------------------------
% And here the actual exam begins
%-----------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
    \question[60]
    The content of this question is irrelevant.
\end{questions}

\maketable

\end{document}
```